# Как написать кнопку в виде стрелки, направленную влево?

Tags: html, css, css3

Подскажите новичку.

Как написать кнопку в виде стрелки, направленную влево, на которую можно было бы наложить тени, бордер и так далее?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте псевдоэлементы [before](http://htmlbook.ru/css/before) и [after](http://htmlbook.ru/css/after) + `transform: rotate`

```css
body {
    margin: 50px;
}
.btn-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #c00;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn-arrow span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-arrow:after, 
.btn-arrow:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    top: 50%;
    background: #c00;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.btn-arrow:before {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-arrow:hover, 
.btn-arrow:hover:after, 
.btn-arrow:hover:before {
    background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-arrow">
    <span>Text</span>
</a>
```

вариант с border

```css
body {
    margin: 50px;
}
.btn-arrow {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #c00;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);    
}
.btn-arrow span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.btn-arrow:after, 
.btn-arrow:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute; left: -22px; top: 50%;
    background: #c00;
    width: 41px;
    height: 41px;
    margin-top: -21px;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
}
.btn-arrow:before {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-arrow:hover{
    color: #c00;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #f00;    
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn-arrow:hover:after, 
.btn-arrow:hover:before {
    background: #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #f00;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.btn-arrow:hover:before {
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn-arrow">
    <span>Text</span>
</a>
```